# Replace symbols in output without evaluation

Tags: evaluation, replacement, symbols, built-in-symbols

I found the Wolfram example for [ExpandNCM](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply.html) but I want a more human-readable output form. I want to evaluate ExpandNCM, for example with `ExpandNCM[(a**b+c**d)**(e**f+g**h)] = a**b**e**f + ...`, but then I need to keep the order of all expression parts (abef+...) *without* those annoying `**`. It isn't allowed to change the position of abef to eabf or something like that. I tried to `ExpandNCM[...]/. NonCommutativeMultiply:>Times` but this doesn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
expandNCM[(h : NonCommutativeMultiply)[a___, b_Plus, c___]] := 
 Distribute[h[a, b, c], Plus, h, Plus, ExpandNCM[h[##]] &]

expandNCM[(h : NonCommutativeMultiply)[a___, b_Times, c___]] := 
 Most[b] ExpandNCM[h[a, Last[b], c]]

expandNCM[a_] := ExpandAll[a]
```

To eliminate `**` operators:

```
compressNCM[expr_] := expr /. NonCommutativeMultiply[x__] :>
   StringJoin@(ToString /@ {x})
```

To return to original notation:

```
toNCM[expr_] := 
 expr /. str_String :> 
   NonCommutativeMultiply @@ (ToExpression /@ Characters[str])

encm = expandNCM[(a ** b + c ** d) ** (e ** f + g ** h)]
```

> a ** b ** e ** f + a ** b ** g ** h + c ** d ** e ** f + c ** d ** g ** h

```
% // compressNCM
```

> abef + abgh + cdef + cdgh

However, the above expression cannot be operated on further without converting back to the normal form with `toNCM`. As written, the conversion back only works for single character factors.

```
encm == % // toNCM
```

> True

Comment: Great help!!!!!